# Navigating to specific screen after login authentication in react native NOT working well

Tags: javascript, react-native, navigation

I have restaurant application where there are two users, the customer and the restaurant owner, I am implementing the login authentication using `react context`, after user enter the login details, object include user data will be returned from server and navigate to specific route based on role value that is returned from the server, So the issue I am facing is that after successful validation, it shows message that login successful but is not navigate to the route for that user, instead it keep in login screen, and when i close the app and open again, directly it navigates to the user route,
here is the `AuthProvider.js` page:

```
export const AuthProvider = ({ children }) => {
    const [user, setUser] = useState(null);
    return (
        <AuthContext.Provider
            value={{
                user,
                setUser,
                login: async (email, password) => {
                    setIsloading(true)
                    try {
                        axios({
                            method: 'POST',
                            url: URL,
                            data: JSON.stringify({
                                email: email,
                                password: password
                            }),
                            headers: {
                                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                            }
                        }).then(res => {
                            let auth = res.data.auth;
                            let userD = res.data.user;
                            let token = res.data.token;
                            if (auth === true) {
                                AsyncStorage.setItem("Token", token);
                                AsyncStorage.setItem("userID", JSON.stringify(userD.user_id));
                                setUser(userD)
                                setIsloading(false)
                                Alert('success');

                            } else {
                                setIsloading(false)
                                Alert('login failed');

                            }
                        })
                    } catch (err) {
                        console.log("Error : ", err);
                        setIsloading(false)
                    }

                } >
            {children}
      
        </AuthContext.Provider >
```

and this is the `Routes.js` page:

```
import React, { useContext, useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { View, ActivityIndicator } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer} from '@react-navigation/native';
import { Provider as StoreProvider } from 'react-redux'
import store from '../store/store';;
import {Provider as PaperProvider} from 'react-native-paper';
import { AuthContext } from './authProvider';
import ResturantStuckScreen from './ResturantStackScreen';
import RootStackScreen from './RootStackScreen';
import CustomerStuckScreen from './CustomerStuckScreen';
import { COLORS } from '../constants'
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage';
import axios from 'axios';

const routes = () => {
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
    const { user, setUser } = useContext(AuthContext);

    useEffect(() => {
        setTimeout(async () => {
            let Token;
            let UserID;
            Token = null;
            UserID = null;
            try {
                Token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('Token');
                UserID = await AsyncStorage.getItem('userID');
            } catch (e) {
                console.log(e);
            }
            await axios.get(Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 'http://192.168.0.103:3000/api/isUserAuth' : 'http://10.0.2.2:3000/api/isUserAuth', {
                headers: { 'x-auth-token': Token },
                params: { userID: UserID }
            }).then((res) => {
                let user = res.data.user[0];
                if (res.data.auth === false) {
                    setUser(null)
                    setIsLoading(false)
                } else {
                    setUser(user)
                    setIsLoading(false)
                }
            }).catch((error) => {
                console.log(error)
                setUser(null)
                setIsLoading(false)
            });

        }, 1000);
    }, []);


    if (isLoading) {
        return (

            <View style={{
                position: 'absolute',
                left: 0,
                right: 0,
                top: 0,
                bottom: 0,
                alignItems: 'center',
                justifyContent: 'center',
                backgroundColor: COLORS.primary

            }}>
                <ActivityIndicator size='large' color='white'></ActivityIndicator>

            </View>
        )

    }

    return (

        <PaperProvider theme={theme}>
            <NavigationContainer theme={theme}>

                {user !== null ? (
                    user.role === 'customer' ?
                        <StoreProvider store={store}>
                                <CustomerStuckScreen />
                        </StoreProvider>
                        :
                        <ResturantStuckScreen />
                ) :
                    <RootStackScreen />

                }
            </NavigationContainer>
        </PaperProvider>


    );
}

export default routes;
```

so it working when i close the app and open it again because the useEffect here, put i don't understand why not navigating in the first time I login.

Comment: What the exact values you are getting in res.data.user?

Comment: @JigneshMayani data related to user something like this `{'name': 'anie', email: 'email@mail.com', role:'customer' ...etc}` @Jignesh Mayani

Comment: were you able to fix this? as i am also facing the same issue.

Comment: @Sakshi actually i have changed to redux instead of context api

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with the below code what the in Routes.js file

```
const routes = () => {
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
    const { user, setUser } = useContext(AuthContext);
    
    console.log('userData : ', user) // log for user data to check the context state..
```

Comment: `{ "email": "test@test.com", "name": "SOSE","phone": "0111368977","role": "restaurant", "user_id": 3}` this is the data in `Routes.js` wich excatly the same one in `AuthProvider.js`